Extracting a subsequence which converges in the $t$-Wasserstein distance?
Posted this to MathOverflow as well.
Assume that $\mu_n$ are probability measures on $\mathbb R ^d$ with finite moments of order $t$, and $\mu_n\to\mu$ weakly.
Clearly, $\int |x|^t d\mu_n(x)$ is a sequence of real numbers, so it has a convergent subsequence. Is there a chance, that the limit happens to be $\int |x|^t d\mu(x)$? This would mean that $\mu_{n_k}\to\mu$ in $t-$Wasserstein distance (assuming one also shows that $\mu$ has a finite moment of order $t$ as well).

Does a weakly convergent sequence always have a convergent subsequence in the $t-$Wasserstein sense?
If not, does the above ever happen, and under what assumptions?

Many thanks for any hints and ideas!

Since you speak about a convergent subsequence, I guess you assume that the moments of order $t$ are bounded, not only finite.
The answer to the first question is still negative. For instance, take random variables $X_n$ with $\mathrm P(X_n = n) = 1-\mathrm P(X_n = n) = n^{-t}$. Then, $X_n \to 0, n\to \infty$, in probability. And the corresponding sequence $(\mu_n)$ of probability distributions on $\mathbb{R}$ does not have a subsequence convergent in $t$-Wasserstein distance, as otherwise the limit would be $0$, which is impossible.
To answer your second question, the necessary and sufficient condition is uniform integrability of order $t$, i.e.
$$
\sup_{n\ge 1}\int_{|x|>N} |x|^t \mu_n (dx) \to 0, \quad N\to\infty. 
$$
Indeed, in this case the sequence of measures is tight, then there is some weakly convergent subsequence $\mu_{n_k}\to \mu$, and their moments of order $t$ converge thanks to the uniform integrability. The necessity follows from the following two facts:

Skorokhod representation theorem: if $\mu_n\to \mu, n\to \infty,$ weakly, then there are ($\mathbb R^d$-valued) random variables $X$ and $(X_n,n\ge 1)$ such that $X_n\to X$, $n\to\infty$, a.s.

Vitali convergence theorem (ad hoc formulation): if $X_n \to X$, $n\to\infty$, a.s., then $\mathrm E|X_n|^t \to \mathrm E|X|^t,n\to\infty$, iff the sequence $(|X_n|^t, n\ge 1)$ is uniformly integrable.


A simple sufficient condition is that for some $r>t$, the moments of order $r$ are bounded. (Thanks to the De la Vallée-Poussin criterion.)

Thank you very much for the answer!
